# Confused about order of operation when using a Matrix in XNA, C#

Tags: c#, vector, matrix, xna

Here are two different pieces of code

This is what I started with

```
Vector2 hold = Vector2.Transform(pos1, mat1);
Matrix inv = Matrix.Invert(mat2);
Vector2 pos2 = Vector2.Transform(hold, inv);
```

And this is what i'm told is the simplified version

```
Matrix matrix1to2 = mat1 * Matrix.Invert(mat2);
Vector2 pos2 = Vector2.Transform(pos1, matrix1to2);
```

What I don't understand is, why isn't the first line in the simpilifed version

```
Matrix matrix1to2 = Matrix.Invert(mat2)*mat1;
```

Since in matrix order the thing on the right would take effect first and in the original we have mat1 being multiplied in first

**Edit:**
The following image shows the order of operations desired

http://www.riemers.net/images/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/mat1.png

The tutorial says that to create this transformation you use;

```
Matrix carriageMat = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -carriage.Height, 0) * Matrix.CreateScale(playerScaling) 
* Matrix.CreateTranslation(xPos, yPos, 0) * Matrix.Identity;
```

Why does this work if the order is left to right?

Comment: I think this is a http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ question. You will have more feedback there.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that. Should I close this then?

Comment: If you want. Probaly some moderators will came at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since in matrix order the thing on the right would take effect first
>   and in the original we have mat1 being multiplied in first

Actually, the "thing on the **left**" takes effect first. Matrices are applied to the vertex in the same order in which you'd read them (assuming you're used to a Latin language).

In XNA, you typically perform transformations in SRT (Scale, Rotate, Translate) order. That way, the object will be scaled and rotated about its own origin (rotating on is own axis) before being moved into world space.

For example: if I wanted to rotate an object by Pi / 2, the move it 100 units along the X axis, I might use:

```
var rotate = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.PiOver2);
var translate = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(100,0,0));

var worldMatrix = rotate * translate;
```

If, instead, I wanted to move the object 100 units to the right, then rotate it about the world origin (0,0,0) to get a sort of orbiting effect (instead of spinning as is done in the first example), I'd use

```
var worldMatrix = translate * rotate;
```

You could also spin the object on its on axis, move it 100 units along the world X axis, the orbit it about the world origin by:

```
var worldMatrix = rotateSpin * translate * rotateOrbit;
```

where `rotateSpin` and `rotateOrbit` are rotation matrices defining your spin (rotation about object's origin) and orbit (rotation about the world origin following translation), respectively. Note that the order in which the operations effect your service vertices is left - to - right.

Comment: David, every discussion I've seen about matrix order, speaks of the operation on the **right** being applied first. For example, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/29265/45120 "first scale the object, then rotate it, then translate it: L = T * R * S".  Please explain what is different, such that you are talking about left-to-right.

Comment: For example, looking at the Riemer diagram referenced in question, and comparing it to the formula shown in question, the **first** transform discussed is between images (1) and (2); it is a change in XY position. In the formula (ignoring the object's Identity transform matrix at the end), this is the **last** matrix `Matrix.CreateTranslation(xPos, yPos, 0)`.  The carriage height transform, which is only in y, is the final change, image (3) becoming (4), and is done by the first matrix `Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -carriage.Height, 0)`

Comment: ... Therefore, IMHO, a *better* explanation is that **both** approaches -- (applying one mult, then applying the second mult) vs (multiplying the two matrices together, then applying the combination) "work the same way":  they **both** can be thought of as "performing the second operation and then the first".  So, you **apply** them in the **opposite** order from which you want them to take effect. When "simplifying" a multi-step formula that works, you **don't** change their order, as you **correctly** say. But when **thinking about** what you end up with, think right to left.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This depends on the convention used in your code and API. For instance, matrices in GLSL are applied in the opposite order of that used in HLSL, because the matrices are transposed (row-major vs column major). In all of the XNA documentation - which is what this question was about six years ago - matrices are applied in the order I specified in the answer. Matrices are associative, but not commutative. (I think - it's been awhile since I was in 8th-grade geometry.)